# Plot dates with Pandas and Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a DataFrame where each row is an event and it has a column of `datetime` values specifying the date and time of the event.

I just want to plot the amount of events for each day and be able to specify the start and end date of the x axis. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you post your sample data

Comment: Not sure how to do that, but imagine a dataframe with just one column, date. I want the X axis to be the date, and the Y axis to be the amount of times this date occurs. 

I'm having trouble with the *dates in the x axis* part.

Comment: Can you give us more details about: `I'm having trouble with the dates in the x axis part.`?

Comment: I do not know how to create a scatter plot where the x axis is a range of dates and the y axis is the amount of times each of these dates occurs in my `DataFrame`. How would I do that if I have, for example, a `DataFrame` with just one column, the column called **dates** which has one `datetime` value in each row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider a `DF` containing a single column having datetime values as shown:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('1/1/2016', periods=10, freq='D'), columns=['Date'])
```

[image]

Concatenate a sample of the original `DF` with itself to create duplicated values(say, 5)

```
df_dups = pd.concat([df, df.sample(n=5, random_state=42)], ignore_index=True)
```

Compute it's unique counts by stacking it into a series object.

```
plotting_df = df_dups.stack().value_counts().reset_index(name='counts')
```

***Scatter Plot:***

As only numerical values are supported for both x and y axis as args for the built-in scatter plot method, we must call the [`plot_date`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot_date) function of matplotlib axes object to retain the dates as it is.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(plotting_df['index'], plotting_df['counts'], fmt='.', color='k')
ax.set_ylim(0, plotting_df['counts'].values.max()+1)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Counts')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The amount/count of events is essentially a histogram where date is your datetime column:

```
df.date = df.date.astype("datetime64")
df.groupby(df.date.dt.day).count().plot(kind="scatter")
```