# How can I create a plot with a datetime range on X-axis holding datetime data values?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe with the following columns

[event_number] = the ID of the event

[register_start] = datetime for event start

[register_deadline] = datetime for event registration deadline

[customer_id] = the ID for the customer (participant/register)

[registered_on] = datetime log for the customers registration to the event

I have tried creating a pivot table, but somehow that is not suited for creating my plot. I would like to create a plot where xticks = the register_start and register_deadline range and then be able to plot each registered_on value in between those ranges for a given event.

[image: Screenshot]

Then i tried something like this:

```
`df1.plot(xticks=df1.iloc[1], y='registered_on')`
```

Comment: You’re probably looking for an eventplot. There are other answers showing how to do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31820578/7758804, https://stackoverflow.com/q/40308365/7758804, https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.eventplot.html

Comment: **[No Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/)**. Always provide a [mre] with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output**, as **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, plot images are okay. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Provide data with [How to provide a reproducible copy of your DataFrame using `df.head(30).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52413246/7758804), then **[edit] your question**, and paste the clipboard into a code block.